# Pin verification failed

Tags: ssl, connection

Kotlin novice. I've been trying for days to connect to an intranet web-site, which uses a self-signed certificate. After trying so long, I imported the public key using a string. The Trustmanager should be correctly initialized, as far as I can see. Below is my code.  Would anybody help me please?

```
try {
                // Load CAs from an InputStream
                val cf: CertificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")

                val srvcaString: String = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
                "MIICnzCCAggCCQCdnO6OZEZRnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBkzELMAkGA1UEBhMC" +
                "SVQxETAPBgNVBAgMCFBpZW1vbnRlMQ8wDQYDVQQHDAZUb3Jpbm8xDTALBgNVBAoM" +
                "BFBDRFAxCzAJBgNVBAsMAlVJMRowGAYDVQQDDBFzcnZjYS51aS5wY2RwLm9yZzEo" +
                "MCYGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYZaG9zdG1hc3RlckBjb3R0b2xlbmdvLm9yZzAeFw0xODAy" +
                "MjAxNjM1MDdaFw0zODAyMTUxNjM1MDdaMIGTMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJVDERMA8GA1UE" +
                "CAwIUGllbW9udGUxDzANBgNVBAcMBlRvcmlubzENMAsGA1UECgwEUENEUDELMAkG" +
                "A1UECwwCVUkxGjAYBgNVBAMMEXNydmNhLnVpLnBjZHAub3JnMSgwJgYJKoZIhvcN" +
                "AQkBFhlob3N0bWFzdGVyQGNvdHRvbGVuZ28ub3JnMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUA" +
                "A4GNADCBiQKBgQDJlFLPFXYGSrh429RTHO4uapJd5iq4pwOLPlvbda+3mNOeuOG+" +
                "SUcGlst9061uZpVrw8L66pJl+37EmQKnokn/a8EmyD9zdf2xujS4ISjO7q5uf3b8" +
                "gg/HbqVr2cH6T5XQrxkXTt8qRqUnbJJKT2q12INyvCUcvg1PjtHsF5RPVwIDAQAB" +
                "MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4GBAH2nPSiXxWebNShutvy3+wrMnIP6WJmF7bLQJLeX" +
                "iDASnew4AikH/xVCxdrms+VMD6ockL4zcyB6eBHb9+HZRX4Mb6KJm91aAOj38g0U" +
                "6R3G4WpgX3m7yfkD/wGSobmaQYfpUQvK0d1xW5aj+7X5Vr+yRZ//2H7OJMKsje6c" +
                "Wafx\n" +
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"

                val caInput = ByteArrayInputStream(srvcaString.toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset()))

                val ca: X509Certificate = caInput.use {
                    cf.generateCertificate(it) as X509Certificate
                }

                val keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType()
                val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType).apply {
                    load(null, null)
                    setCertificateEntry("ca", ca)
                }

                // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs inputStream our KeyStore
                val tmfAlgorithm: String = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()
                val tmf: TrustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm).apply {
                    init(keyStore)
                }


                // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
                val context: SSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS").apply {
                    init(null, tmf.trustManagers, null)
                }

                // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
                val url = URL("https://srvca.ui.pcdp.org/ca/checkAuto.php?numprog=" + inNumprog)
                val urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
                urlConnection.sslSocketFactory = context.socketFactory


                val httpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

                httpURLConnection.readTimeout = 8000
                httpURLConnection.connectTimeout = 8000
                httpURLConnection.doOutput = true
                httpURLConnection.connect() /


                //... other code

                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    
            }
```

I get the exception: "Pin verification failed"

Comment: Can you please give a detailed log/screenshot of the error and the response. That will help people debug better. Also, as a good practice never keep  your keys in code (or share them on Stackoverflow or any other site)

Comment: @YuvrajJaiswal No, no screenshots. Only text in question. Images make it difficult to read, grep, copy, etc.  PS: where do you see a key in the code above? An X.509 certificate is by definition public data.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek agreed.Text should be the first priority wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how related this is, but I had the same error with a react native app and I found that if I exported as a base64 cert it failed, but if I exported it as a DER encoded binary it worked.

[image: This Works]